# How many object instances are being created here?

Tags: c++, object, memory-management

There was c++ code that looked something like this [in a tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4vZIF-uMzs&list=PLAE85DE8440AA6B83&index=51) (line numbers added for clarity):

```
1.  Config defaultConfig("/etc/foobar/config");
2.  Config userConfig("~/.config/foobar/config");
3.  Config conf;
4.  /* Do something else not involving `conf` */
5.  conf = defaultConfig.join(userConfig);
```

My question is, how many instances of the `Config` class are being created?

In this case, the `join` function returns a new `Config` instance, rather than modifying the existing one, so at least 3 objects are being created.

My question is about the third line (`Config conf;`). Does c++ automatically create a `Config` instance on that line (even though in other language, such as Java, you would have to manually tell it to assign a `new Config()`)? Or is the `c++` compiler smart enough to realize that the `conf` object is never accessed, but instead gets replaced on line #5?

How much memory is allocated? Enough for three references and four `Config` instances, or is there more going on behind the scenes?

Comment: The answer cannot be determined by the code you posted.  This is especially the case due to line 5.  We don't know how `join` is declared, if it takes a `Config` by value or not.  We don't know if the compiler will optimize copies away, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

C++ isn't Java, so there are no references here, just class objects. Like you say, there are likely 3+1 objects created by your code.

You can delay the creation of the third object by not declaring it until needed, by removing line 3 and making line 5

```
Config conf = defaultConfig.join(userConfig);
```

That way there will very likely only be 3 objects created.

Comment: Could be more objects, depending on how the parameter to `join` is declared.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Could be any number of objects, if `join` creates extra copies and stores somewhere else.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Does c++ automatically create a Config instance on that line

Yep, three instances are created on the stack with automatic storage duration.

> Or is the c++ compiler smart enough to realize that the conf object is never accessed, but instead gets replaced on line #5?

*Probably* not. An implementation is allowed to make optimizations that don't affect the end result, but here the object is *initialized*. (Again, this would definitely be implementation- and compiler option-dependent.)

> How much memory is allocated? Enough for three references and four Config instances, or is there more going on behind the scenes?

Hard to say. At least three, but maybe four for the return value from `join` (which would then be assigned to `conf` if things were unoptimized).

Comment: _"on the stack"_ That's an implementation detail. Just leave the storage duration part in.

Comment: _"but here the object is initialized"_ Where?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you asking, or saying I should clarify that `conf` is initialized on line 3?

Comment: I'm asking.  `conf` _is_ default-initialised but that doesn't have much to do with what you're saying. I wondered whether maybe you were calling the later assignment an initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

> Enough for three references and four Config instances, or is there more going on behind the scenes?

Wow yeah you really are coming from Java. There are no "references" here. It's much simpler.

Assuming that `join` returns by value:

- You have three `Config` objects, fully declared and allocated, on your first three lines;
- A fourth `Config` object is instantiated in the `join` call, as a temporary; it won't live for very long, because as soon as its used for the assignment into the third object, it is destroyed;
- `join` may well involve further temporary instantiations, particularly if it takes `userConfig` by value, but we cannot see that from your question.

So, in total you are creating four or more objects, but by the time your function ends you assuredly only have three left.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 1 and 2: you cannot tell how those functions work, so they create at least 1 object each. Those will be "put on the stack", which means roughly that they will be destructed when execution leaves the scope they were declared in.
Line 3: `Config conf;` means that a new `Config` object is created using the default constructor of the `Config` class.

Comment: So, does that mean 4 instances of the class are created, and 4 "chunks" of memory allocated for?

Comment: @IQAndreas: Yes, but the fourth will be temporary (prior to its assignment into the third) and may be optimised away entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Line 1,2,3 create an object each.
Line 5 does not result in creation of a new object in the calling function. The data members of the existing object **conf** get overwritten by the data members of the object returned by **join()** function.
So in total, after line 5, 3 objects are present in memory

The concept is kind of similar to the one in the code below :-

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
x = sum(x,y); //adds x,y and returns 15
```

Now, in the above code, the third line does not create a new variable and store 15 in it. It just overwrites the existing value of  variable x.
I hope this makes things clear

Comment: _"Line 5 does not result in creation of a new object."_ You do not know that. The OP in fact suggests otherwise.

Comment: `Line 5 does not result in creation of a new object.`  How do you know this?  You don't know if `join` takes a `Config` by value, thus will more than likely create a new (temporary) object.

Comment: I mean for the calling function, it does not result in the creation of a new object. Of course, inside 'join' a new object is created but not in the calling function.